# do communities not have guest users?

Tags: customer-community

Typically with a Force.com site and customer portal if the user hasn't logged in yet you can create a debug log by adding SiteName Guest User to the debug log. Does this option not exist for Communities? I've overridden the standard Community login page with my own and I'd like to be able to see debug logs for this user before they login. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

Yes I have configured a community and then used the force.com site with VF pages for customization. The Site does have a default profile as usual. You can see the name of the guest user under "Assigned users". So this user does exist.

I just tried to add this user to the debug logs but could not find it when searching for it. I never had a need to add this user to the log before.

I came across this link which could possibly help in adding this user to the debug logs. Maybe a change in Winter 14 prevents adding certain types of users to the log.

http://www.salesforcetutorial.com/administrator-cannot-setup-debug-logs-for-certain-users/

Comment: Thanks, well I'll be creating a custom login and registration page so I assume I'll need debug statements at some point. My org is still Summer '13 so it can't be an issue unique to Winter '14.

Comment: So is the answer no it is not possible?

Comment: Did you have any success with that workaround? Else to the best of my knowledge, we cannot add this user to the debug logs.

Comment: I believe the fix was enabling self-registration for the community. then I was able to create a debug log for the guest user. I can't think of any other changed I made that would have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am now able to add the guest user to the debug log. I believe the fix was enabling self-registration for the community. then I was able to create a debug log for the guest user. I can't think of any other changed I made that would have resolved the issue.